# Google reCAPTCHA: how to generate captcha token on the server side

Tags: google-cloud-platform, recaptcha

I've added the Google reCAPTCHA enterprise to my auth endpoints, and now I want to cover them by integration tests. To do so, I need to generate a valid token and pass it to requests. But I can't find in the docs how to do that, they only offer to create a separate reCAPTCHA key for testing environment which is not suitable for me, because I want to test production too.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with [multi-factor authentication](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/integrate-account-verification) and [an assessment](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/integrate-account-verification?hl=en#request_assessment)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you, but I utilized test keys for testing Recaptcha using Cypress , [here you can find them](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do) and more information about what you want